# PHP (Only) Backend Framework

Tags: php, frameworks

after hours of search i ask this question now.
im searching for a php framework what has only a backend part for command line tools like database config and a folder structure.

I dont need any frontend/web parts.

Comment: Pretty much any modern framework allows you to use only the parts you require, if you are looking for a shallow learning curve google for a microframework. Also, recommendation questions are off topic here, so this question will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) all of this stuff is really easy and you don't have to use the frontend/web part at all.

Comment: Was just about to say the same thing. +1'ed you :)